# Sharing variables across multiple sessions

Tags: apache, nginx, node.js

I know I cannot have a global variable in my backend code (java or php or something else) and have different users (and hence sessions) see the same value. If I need to share some values across these user sessions I need to write them to a DB and read it out every time. This seems awfully wasteful to me.

I understand that an apache process (or the app server) will fork and so having global values will not work but if I am looking at a specialized application is there a web server that lets me do this? This should be possible in a web server that uses threads instead of forking processes. But if I need to share global memory I will need to have some kind of locks to properly access them. I understand that it could (and mostly will) get really buggy but will it degrade performance compared to a DB?

Thoughts?

- Pav

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's entirely true. Apache will handle each user connection individually - correct. However, I know that in Java it is possible to have a Singleton object that exists for the life of the application, in which you could potentially store values to be used across all user sessions.

When handling each user connection on the server side, each access to this Singleton will access the same object - therefore the same values.

You might want to do some more research into application scope objects as well. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve due to lack of a use case, but you may find that Java web apps can do more than you expect in this area.